# Disable camera completely

Tags: camera

I'm writing a program that depends on the camera.  I need to test how my program reacts when the camera is not present or disabled.

Is there a way to turn it off completely?

Comment: Well, you could always take a Sharpie™ to the lens. Honestly you'd probably need a custom ROM to do that.

Comment: If your application requires a camera, you should use the [android manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) to declare that your app requires it. This will prevent the app from being displayed in the market on devices which don't have a camera.